# How to sum columns in Select-Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am selecting different columns and want to create another column which calculates in a specific way. How do I solve this when the columns are created at once and they are declared in the select part.

I tried to put them in the `FROM` statement, but I think I did it wrong, wasn't really obvious for me how to do it. I also tried to "replace" each single sum with the whole query for it but it didn't work out either.

```
SELECT 

SUM(CASE WHEN 
Table.Code = 'Golden' 
THEN
Booking.Amount 
ELSE 
0.0 
END) AS Money1,

SUM(CASE WHEN 
Table.Code = 'Monkey' 
THEN
Booking.Amount 
ELSE 
0.0 
END) AS Money2,

(Money1 + Money2) AS "Golden Monkey"

FROM Table
Where ...
```

Its always underlined with the text "invalid column name". How can I Fix this?

Comment: The select list can't reference other select list columns. Use a derived table, and do the Golden Monkey outside it.

Comment: You can use repeat the expression or use subquery, CTE, or lateral join to define columns.  You cannot re-use the column aliases in the same `select` where they are defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use cte, you can not use alias of a column name in same level

```
with cte as
(
SELECT 

SUM(CASE WHEN 
Table.Code = 'Golden' 
THEN
Booking.Amount 
ELSE 
0.0 
END) AS Money1,

SUM(CASE WHEN 
Table.Code = 'Monkey' 
THEN
Booking.Amount 
ELSE 
0.0 
END) AS Money2 


FROM Table
Where ...
) select (Money1 + Money2) AS "Golden Monkey" from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - since you can not use the column alias name to calculate another column

```
SELECT 

SUM(CASE WHEN Table.Code = 'Golden' THEN Booking.Amount ELSE 0.0 END) AS Money1,
SUM(CASE WHEN Table.Code = 'Monkey' THEN Booking.Amount ELSE 0.0 END) AS Money2,
SUM(CASE WHEN Table.Code in ('Golden','Monkey') THEN Booking.Amount ELSE 0.0 END) as "Golden Monkey"
FROM Table Where ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use subquery to get your desired result.

```
Select money1, money2, money1 + moeny2 from (
    SELECT 

    SUM(CASE WHEN 
    Table.Code = 'Golden' 
    THEN
    Booking.Amount 
    ELSE 
    0.0 
    END) AS Money1,

    SUM(CASE WHEN 
    Table.Code = 'Monkey' 
    THEN
    Booking.Amount 
    ELSE 
    0.0 
    END) AS Money2

    FROM Table
    Where ...
) as d
```